# Symfony 2 with PUGXMultiUserBundle and multi login form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

here my problem : I have two categories of users in my application (locataires and propriétaires), and i need one (or two) login form. I use PUGXMultiUserBundle to manage all my users.

here is the view for loggin "proprietaires" :

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
    Nous contacter - {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}


    {# Contents #}
    {% block body %}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">
                    <form action="{{ path('proprietaire_login_check') }}" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Secure Sign in</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign in
                            </button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

My file  app/config/config.yml :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        user_manager: pugx_user_manager

pugx_multi_user:
  users:
    proprietaire:
        entity: 
          class: AppBundle\Entity\Proprietaire
#          factory: 
        registration:
          form: 
            type: AppBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationProprietaireFormType
            name: fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
          template: proprietaire.form.html.twig
        profile:
          form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProfileProprietaireFormType
            name: fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile, Default] 
    locataire:
        entity: 
          class: AppBundle\Entity\Locataire
        registration:
          form: 
            type: AppBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationLocataireFormType
          template: locataire.form.html.twig
        profile:
          form: 
            type: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProfileLocataireFormType
```

And my file app/config/security.yml :

```
security:

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

        proprietaire:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Proprietaire
                property: username

        locataire:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Locataire
                property: username

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
#            form_login:
#                provider: fos_userbundle
#                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
#            logout:
#                path:        /logout
#                target:      /
            anonymous:    true

        proprietaire_firewall:
            pattern: .*
            form_login:
                # Soumet le formulaire de connection ici
                provider: fos_userbundle
                check_path: /proprietaire_login_check
            logout:
                path:   /proprietaire_logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/profile, role: ROLE_USER }
```

I begin with symfony 2,  and I don't understand how to create a login form for the users "proprietaires" and one other for the users "locataires". And how to configure the differents firewalls in the the file security.yml ?

Another question : in your opinion, I have to create differents "roles" in my security.yml file ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The PUGXMultiUserBundle is build on top of the FOSUserBundle, it helps managing different types of users using doctrine table inheritance, looking at your database, you can see how there is a parent table "User" and two child tables "locataire" and "proprietaire". By different types of users is meant the point where there is a difference; for example: the registration of a user: there is a difference in the form's fields and the profile editing form is also different. All the rest where there is no difference between the users, the login to the website, the profile page, the logout action... are all handled, as usual directly by the FOSUserBundle.

SO concretely, yes you can use one login form for your two users( Actually I'm using a login form for three different users). You don't need a firewall per user, one firewall is enough. And yes, probably you need to define roles in access control section because you would have to secure an url relevant to the locataire only, for example: /locataire/pays/rent/1 , (the best way to give a user a role is in the class constructor like this:

```
public function __construct() {

parent::__construct();
$this->roles = array('ROLE_LOCATAIRE');
};
```

)

So in your security.yml file:

```
security:

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        OC\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512


    providers:
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:        ^/
            anonymous:      true
            provider:       main
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true                
                default_target_path: /profile
            logout:
                path:       fos_user_security_logout
                target:     /index

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_LOCATAIRE: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_PROPRIETAIRE: ROLE_USER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/locataire, roles: ROLE_LOCATAIRE }
        - { path: ^/proprietaire, roles: ROLE_PROPRIETAIRE }
```

I hope this helps you, I know how this does look to a newbie because I've been there. Take your time and I'm here if you need any help.