# How to configure two login for two different users using PUGXMultiUserBundle and FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I have two login templates for two different users.
I want login 1 to connect only the user of type 1 and login 2 to connect only the user of type 2.

I'm using PUGXMultiUserBundle / FOSUserBundle – Symfony 3.

I configured PUGXMultiUserBundle and overrided the fosuserbundle template and I created two firewall for each user.

I am new to symfony I need a little help how to do this.

Comment: I would go with symfony guard instead of `PUGXMultiUserBundle / FOSUserBundle` and just create 2 Authenticators, and to distinguish user I would go with some kind of flag field in user entity or maybe use roles.

Comment: I used PUGXMultiUserBundle to register both users in the database. 
for the symfony guard how to use it? 
in my user table I have a 'type' field to distinguish the two users with a 'roles' field

Comment: hello, can i use symfony guard with FOSUserBundle ?

Answer (score 0):

Did this task. I used official [documentation](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). Follow the tutorial and all will be fine.

Comment: Hello, I have already followed the documentation of PUGXMultiUserBundle  my problem is with the login. I tried to do guard Authenticators with FOSUserBundle and i created two Firewalls. 
but I still have connection problems with the second user. I can not verify if the second user is logged in and have the admin role and 
both of templates login 1 and 2 allows to pass both types of users.

Comment: Maybe this solution help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749208/symfony-2-with-pugxmultiuserbundle-and-multi-login-form